# Customizing HttpConfiguration of Jetty with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm using spring boot (1.2.1 as of now) and I need to increase the default 8k request header size limit which lives in `HttpConfiguration` class in Jetty. Looking into `JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` which I can get hold of via `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` but can't see the way how to change that.

I did have a look on the `JettyServerCustomizer` as well - I understand I can get hold of the jetty `Server` via that but again - no way how to change the `HttpConfiguration` here.

Any tips will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a `JettyServerCustomizer` to reconfigure the `HttpConfiguration` but it's buried a little bit in Jetty's configuration model:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer customizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                customizeJetty((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container);
            }
        }

        private void customizeJetty(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jetty) {
            jetty.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {

                @Override
                public void customize(Server server) {
                    for (Connector connector : server.getConnectors()) {
                        if (connector instanceof ServerConnector) {
                            HttpConnectionFactory connectionFactory = ((ServerConnector) connector)
                                    .getConnectionFactory(HttpConnectionFactory.class);
                            connectionFactory.getHttpConfiguration()
                                    .setRequestHeaderSize(16 * 1024);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Ha, I gave up when reached the Connectors and didn't go the downcast way and further! Thank you very much